# Hiding row if cell equals next visible cell

Tags: excel, vba, visible

I am trying to write a macro that hides the row if the cell value equals the next visible cell in that column and loops through the whole column. I have read that SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) only works up to 8192 cells and my spreadsheet has 15,000 rows.

I have tried something like this but want to restrict it to only visible cells

```
Sub Test()
For i = 7 To 15258
    If Range("P" & i).Value = Range("P" & i + 1).Value Then
        Rows(i).Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I have tried to search for a solution but haven't been able to find one yet.

Thanks!

Comment: The limit of 8192 was fixed with Excel 2010 - are you still using an older version? See https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win003.htm

Comment: It is 8192 areas (non-contiguous cells) and not cells so there's less likelihood of getting error for visible cells. Did you test before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be surprised if this couldn't be optimized just a little bit, but it will work for what you are needing.

You can follow the comments within the code itself to kind of get a sense of what it's doing, but in a nutshell, you are using a `For...Next` statement to loop through your visible cells. For each visible cell, you will search for the *next visible cell* and then check to see if that matches. If it does, you add that cell to a special range that tracks all the rows to hide at the end of the code, then hide it.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lookupRng As Range, rng As Range, lstRow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    lstRow = 15258
    Set lookupRng = ws.Range("P7:P" & lstRow)

    Dim rngToHide As Range, i As Long
    For Each rng In lookupRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Application.StatusBar = "Checking row " & rng.Row & " for matches."
        For i = rng.Row + 1 To lstRow                   'Loop through rows after rng
            If Not ws.Rows(i).Hidden Then               'Check if row is hidden
                If rng.Value = ws.Cells(i, "P") Then    'check if the non-hidden row matches
                    If rngToHide Is Nothing Then        'Add to special range to hide cells
                        Set rngToHide = ws.Cells(i, "P")
                    Else
                        Set rngToHide = Union(rngToHide, ws.Cells(i, "P"))
                    End If
                End If
                Exit For                                'Exit the second For statement
            End If
        Next i
    Next rng

    Application.StatusBar = "Hiding duplicate rows"
    If Not rngToHide Is Nothing Then rngToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you got your code K.Davis. For some reason it is not hiding the duplicate cells though.

An example output in row P after the advanced filter is applied is:
2
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
12
20
24
24

Comment: You will need to change the `1` in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` to whatever sheet index you are using, or simply use the sheet name `....Worksheets("Data Sheet")` in between quotation marks.

Comment: I missed that part the first time round. Thanks! it works now.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help